# Fedora 25 Tigervnc displays Black screen

Tags: x11, vnc, fedora-25

The system is Fedora 25. The issue is vncviewer is displaying a black screen. By comparison the vnc package list is the same as those in a Fedora 24 system where vnc viewer is displaying correctly.The same client system is used to access the server.

Other threads with this issue have been reviewed and tried, specifically vnc package requirements, `$HOME//.vnc/xstartup permissions`, and suggestions for the xstartup script.

Below is the xstartup script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec gnome-session 
# --session=gnome-fallback
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic & 
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
startx &
```

Below is the output from systemctl status vncserver:

```
vncserver@:2.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:2.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-01-13 07:05:58 PST; 1h 18min ago
Process: 25119 ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 25152 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver %i (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 25147 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i (code=exited, 
status=2)
Main PID: 25161 (Xvnc)
Tasks: 186 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/system-vncserver.slice/vncserver@:2.service
   ├─25161 /usr/bin/Xvnc :2 -auth /home/dan/.Xauthority -desktop server:2 
   (dan) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x
   ├─25168 /usr/bin/vncconfig -nowin
   ├─25170 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary
   ├─25177 dbus-launch --autolaunch 98c684d1ace64647a9df44e5b61d8590 --
binary-syntax --close-stderr
   ├─25178 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog-only --fork --print-pid 5 --
print-address 7 --session
   ├─25182 dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/libexec/gnome-session binary
   ├─25183 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog --fork --print-pid 5 --print-
address 7 --session
   ├─25191 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher
   ├─25196 /bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-
spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
   ├─25199 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
   ├─25203 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
   ├─25222 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets
   ├─25242 /usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon
   ├─25252 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
   ├─25296 /usr/libexec/tracker-extract
   ├─25301 /usr/libexec/tracker-store
   ├─25318 /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-apps
   ├─25320 /usr/libexec/evolution/evolution-alarm-notify
   ├─25324 /usr/libexec/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
   ├─25329 /usr/libexec/gsd-printer
   ├─25335 /usr/libexec/imsettings-daemon
   ├─25336 /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-user-guides
   ├─25378 abrt-applet
   ├─25418 /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs
   ├─25438 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
   ├─25462 /usr/bin/seapplet
   ├─25529 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
   ├─25559 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon -r --xim
```

There were several threads a few years back. Those have been reviewed and tried. They do not seem applicable to this situation.

Comment: I have the same problem on fedora-26

Answer (score 2):

You can find an answer here: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_25&p=desktop&f=6 - on my case the replacement at /home/USER/.vnc/xstartup

```
...
# end line: comment out and add like follows
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#exec /usr/bin/mate-session
exec /usr/bin/gnome-session
```

so I used gnome-session instead of mate-session as I am using gnome-desktop.
No more blank screen (wait some time until transmitted).

Comment: Addendum: As display numbers :0 and :1 were used by the system/gui/gnome itself I decided to use :2 and :3 for vncserver only.

Comment: ADDENDUM_2: Unfortunately, it only works, if vncserver ist startet manually from within its user, not by enabling service startup at boot time.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Fedora 27 and having the same issue "Black Screen". I tried a lot of 'workaround', none of them works for me. then I switched to use MATE desktop environment, and got it working in seconds. if you had struggled with the issue for a long time, i would suggest to  try MATE desktop.

if you don't have MATE installed, you should install MATE:

```
dnf -y group install "MATE Desktop"
```

[here is the help of installing MATE.](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_28&p=desktop&f=4)
update xstartup as follows.

```
#!/bin/sh
#def
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
exec /usr/bin/mate-session
```

remember to restart VNC service, it should work.

```
#systemctl start vncserver@:1.service
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue in F25 with gnome. I just modified the xstartup like the following, and it started working well:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

exec gnome-session
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

Comment: That did not work. Can you provide a copy of your vncserver file. Also an application overlay is displayed, owncloud. However gnome is not running. I am beginning to believe this may be a gnome config issue and not either an xstartup or vncserver config issue.

Answer (score 0):

what about to add a config for xstartup in ~/.vcn/

```
!/bin/sh
#
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
gnome-session &
```